# Need to extract firstname using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I am trying to get the firstname value from a string which is like

> 'firstname' => 'ROBERT','

and i tried this regex

> preg_match_all("/\bfirstname:\s*'\K[\w-]+/", $d);

have not succeeded with this ..

any guess ?

Comment: try this https://regex101.com/r/cxZM9a/1

Comment: Better yet: provide the complete string, it looks like some array, doesn't it?

Comment: Is your input string PHP code?

Answer (score 1):

This works fine:

```
'firstname' => '(\w+)'
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/k5odYZ/1

Answer (score 1):

Seriously undervalued is the `\Q...\E` sequence which might be helpful in your case:

```
\Q'firstname' => \E # look for 'firstname' => literally
(["'])              # capture one of " or '
(.+?)               # capture anything else lazily afterwards ...
\1                  # ... up to group 1
```

See it [**working on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/cxZM9a/4).

Besides, as already posted in the comments, please update your question to have all of your strings in there. There might be easier ways then using a regular expression.